# Slider not working on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using a slider, it is working fine on Firefox but it is not working on IE,

The jQuery code that I am using is

```
$(function() {
    $('#foo0').carouFredSel(
    {
        auto: {
            duration:1500,      
        }
    }, 
    {
        transition: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello Everyone,
I have fixed it

the new code is
    $(function() {


            $('#foo0').carouFredSel(
            {
                auto: {
                    duration:'1500',
                    effect:'slide'

                }
            }, {
                transition: true
            }
            );



        });

Comment: I think we should design another site for every version of IE!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra comma after the last key/value pair of your inner object literal:

```
auto: {
    duration:1500,  // <-- There.
}
```

You should remove it. This is known to cause a syntax error in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier.